# Selecting absent value from Postgres JSONB field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table `entries` with a field `details` which type is `jsonb` and default value is `'{}'::jsonb`, on PostgreSQL 10.5

When I run

```
SELECT details->foo FROM entries
```

I get an

> ERROR:  column "foo" does not exist.

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html I understood that I should get a `NULL` value when the key is not present is the JSON. Did I understand wrongly ? If so, how can I extract the field with a default value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the JSON key as a string constant:

```
SELECT details -> 'foo' 
FROM entries;
```